# Passing struct type to methods or UDFS in spark sql dataframes

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes and I have joined them and after joining in the joined dataframe , i have got two columns which are of type struct. Basically they are of Array[[String,Int]]. I need to derive a third column based on the elements of this struct type.

My code looks like below.

```
val bdf = Seq(
 ("a",1,1,10)
,("a",1,2,10)
,("a",1,3,10)
,("a",1,4,10)
,("b",1,1,20)
,("b",1,2,10)
,("a",2,3,10)
,("a",2,4,20)
,("a",2,5,20)
,("c",2,1,10)
,("c",2,2,20)
,("c",2,3,20)
).toDF("contract_number","linenumber","monthdel","open_quant")

val gbdf = bdf.withColumn("bmergedcol",struct(bdf("monthdel"),bdf("open_quant"))).groupBy("contract_number","linenumber").agg(collect_list("bmergedcol"))





val pl = Seq(
("a",1,"FLAT",10)
,("a",1,"FLAT",30)
,("a",1,"NFE",10)
,("b",1,"FLAT",10)
,("b",1,"NFE",10)
,("c",2,"NFE",10)
,("a",3,"NFE",20)
,("c",2,"FLAT",20)).toDF("connum","linnum","type","qnt")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 
val gpl = pl.withColumn("mergedcol",struct(pl("type"),pl("qnt"))).groupBy("connum","linnum").agg(collect_list("mergedcol"))


val jdf = gbdf.join(gpl,expr("((contract_number = connum) AND (linenumber = linnum ))"),"left_outer")
```

My output of jdf is like

[image]

I need to understand how can i pass the two struct type fields to some method and derive a third one from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both array of structs should enter your UDF as `Seq[Row]`, which you can then map into tuples by specifing the types of the structs (i think its string,int in your case). In this example I use pattern-matching on `Row`, but there are also other ways to do it (e.g. using `Row#.getAs`):

```
val myUDF = udf((arr1:Seq[Row],arr2:Seq[Row]) => {
  // convert to tuples
  val arr1Tup: Seq[(String, Int)] = arr1.map{case Row(s:String,i:Int) => (s,i)}
  val arr2Tup: Seq[(String, Int)] = arr2.map{case Row(s:String,i:Int) => (s,i)}
  // now do derive new quantities
})
```

Using the 2 Sequences of Tuples you can derive your new column

Answer (score 0):

User-Defined Functions (aka UDF) is a feature of Spark SQL to define new Column-based functions transforming Datasets. An UDF could be used to pass the two struct type fields to derive a result.

```
val customUdf = udf((col1: Seq[Row], col2: Int) => {
  // This is an example.
  col1(1).getAs[String]("type") + "--" + col2
})
val cdf = jdf.withColumn("custom", customUdf(jdf.col("collect_list(mergedcol)"), jdf.col("linnum")))
cdf.show(10)
```

In above udf col1 is Seq[Row] as it an array of struct type, If only struct type has to be accessed than simply Row should be used.

Comment: Is it possible to convert this Seq[row] to List and access each row element as tuple

Comment: It might be doable however it will complex the things, access Seq[Row] iterate on it and extract which ever column/value is useful from the row.